# Why does virtualenv throw an error when I try to define the python version as 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I tried to create a new virtualenv directory with `sudo virtualenv curdir -p /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7` and it threw the following error:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.6.4', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 785, in main
    popen = subprocess.Popen([interpreter, file] + sys.argv[1:], env=env)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 741, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 1356, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I understand that I was not allowed to do that, but why? python 2.7 is located there and I want to use it. Is there any way to use it in my virtualenv?

I hope that this isn't too basic of a question. I am still pretty new to Unix command line.

Comment: Hmmm ... I thought `sudo` was magic and allowed you to do anything ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to point to the python executable, which you are not doing here. Its located at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`. Run this

```
    sudo virtualenv curdir -p /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```